# Apache Camel with Spring Boot integration REST API

Tags: curl, post, postman

I'm learning Apache Camel with Spring Boot and I've been trying to follow this example: https://www.baeldung.com/apache-camel-spring-boot.

It tells me to run the file and make a POST request to http://localhost:8080/camel/api/bean and include the HEADER:
`Content-Type: application/json` and a body payload of  `{"id": 1,"name": "World"}`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can download Postman and use that to make requests.

Answer (score 0):

It means you run the Application.class file from your IDE and send POST request using cURL or POSTMAN ( a software you need to download)

POST is a request method supported by HTTP used by the World Wide Web. You can read more about POST request [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))

cURL is a command line tool and stands for Client URL. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)

cURL example:

```
curl -d '{"id": 1,"name": "World"}' -X POST http://localhost:8080/camel/api/bean
```

**Postman** is a great tool when trying to dissect RESTful APIs made by others or test ones you have made yourself. It offers a sleek user interface with which to make HTML requests, without the hassle of writing a bunch of code just to test an API's functionality.

Download PostMan from [here](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)

[Here](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/a-pithy-perusal-of-post-and-put-and-patch-52a7f6443ceb#:%7E:text=POST%20requests&text=In%20Postman%2C%20change%20the%20method,along%20with%20the%20POST%20request.&text=If%20this%20is%20successful%2C%20you,new%20data%20in%20your%20%27db.) is a  tutorial to send POST request using PostMan App

However there are many other nice [alternatives](https://www.producthunt.com/alternatives/postman) to Postman which you can try out too.